# Django Rest Framework: best way to populate field manually

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Considering following model:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='requests')
```

And a viewSet with create/update:

```
class RequestViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
```

I want to set user only on Create and not on Update

First solution:

```
class RequestViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    def pre_save(self, obj):
        create = False
        try:
            if not obj.user:
                create = True
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            create = True
        if create:
            obj.user = self.request.user
```

Second solution using restore_object:

```
class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        create = not instance
        instance = super(RequestSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
        if create:
            request = self.context['request']
            instance.user = request.user
        return instance
```

What's more logical?
I tend to prefer first one (except the try/except but I find no alternative for it)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of class based views, I prefer fat models and thin views.

I would opt for an post_save signal on Request and check the created param.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save

```
Request(...):
    @classmethod
    def post_save(cls, sender, instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
        if raw:
            return
        if created:
            pass  # do your on create stuff here

post_save.connect(Request.post_save, sender=Request, dispatch_uid="uniqueid")  # use weak=False if you use a local function
```

Also note that instance.save() triggers the save signals again, so you might consider to just use .update() if you want to avoid all your signals to be processed again (or even worse, create a signal loop ;-) )